# Already selected options which are disabled should not give to remove in select 2

Tags: jquery-select2

Is there an option to block 'remove option' (or hide remove button) from tags which are already selected and disabled.

Here is my code in jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/wphqwvLf/734/

```
<select id="test" multiple>
    <option val="1" selected disabled>1111</option>
    <option val="2">222</option>
    <option val="3" >333</option>
    <option val="4" disabled>444</option>
</select>

$(function () {
    $('select')
        .select2( { 
            tags: true
        }  
    )
    .on('change', function(){
        //console.log( $(this).val() );
    })
     .on('select2:unselecting',function(){
        console.log('removes' );
    });
});
```

In that code, I need to remove 'remove button' in 1111 tag OR disable 1111 from removing.